# How do I use the join method to join multiple rows from a file to one string?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, so bear with me.  I have a text file that I'm loading with one column of numbers.  I can load the file and loop through them in the code below, but how can I place them into one string?

file data(each number on separte line,return carriage);
12345
54321
22222

end result;
'12345','54321','22222'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        ArrayList combine = new ArrayList();

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
            //just running through so i can see what it's retrieving
            MessageBox.Show(line);
        }

        file.Close();

        // Suspend the screen.
```

Comment: Insted of using ArrayList use List<T> or other container. You will get more type safety and avoid boxing/unboxing (program may run faster)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx). It reads all the lines and returns them as a single string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) to put the lines of the file in an array, and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to concatenate these lines. For example:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt");
string join = String.Join(" ", lines);
```

In this example, `join` will contain all the lines of the file concatenated into a single string, delimited by spaces.
You can use whatever delimiter you wish simply by passing it in as the first argument to `String.Join` (e.g., if you wanted the lines to be separated by a comma and a space, you'd call `String.Join(", ", lines)`). Hope this helps.